# Ignore SSL errors with playwright code generation

Tags: ssl, jestjs, code-generation, end-to-end, playwright

I am using the jest-playwright library (https://github.com/playwright-community/jest-playwright) to perform end-to-end testing. In the jest.config.js file you can set an option to ignore SSL errors:

```
contextOptions: {
   ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
}
```

This works fine when running the tests with jest.
Now, I would want playwright to generate the code when clicking on website elements with the command `npx playwright codegen example.com`. However, playwright stops because of the SSL error when opening the website.

Is there an option to ignore SSL errors when using playwright code generation?

Comment: Similar file is called `playwright.config.ts` for Playwright. But you might want to consider specifying that config in the "code" instead of your global config.

Answer (score 13):

Another option is to configure the `test` to ignore the HTTPS errors.

```ts
import { test } from "@playwright/test";

test.use({
  ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
});

test("test", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto(
    "https://example.com/"
  );
});
```

*NB - `test.use...` is what's included when running `npx playwright codegen --ignore-https-errors`*.

---

**UPDATE** The setting can also be included in your `playwright.config.ts` file ([see docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration#global-configuration)).

```ts
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';
export default defineConfig({
  use: {
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
  },
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly - is there any way it could be included in the playwright.config file?

Comment: You can include the setting in the global config yes. https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration#global-configuration. 

I'll update my answer to include that as well.

Answer (score 11):

You can run [codegen with custom setup](https://playwright.dev/docs/cli#codegen-with-custom-setup). Just call [`page.pause()`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page/#pagepause) in your initial script which will open codegen controls  if you run `node my-initial-script.js`.

The [example code](https://playwright.dev/docs/cli#codegen-with-custom-setup) with [`browser.newContext({ ignoreHTTPSErrors: true })`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browser#browsernewcontextoptions) would look like this:

```js
// my-initial-script.js
const { chromium } = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  // Make sure to run headed.
  const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false });

  // Setup context however you like.
  const context = await browser.newContext({ /* pass any options */ ignoreHTTPSErrors: true });

  // Pause the page, and start recording manually.
  const page = await context.newPage();
  await page.pause();
})();
```

Then you can visit https://expired.badssl.com/ without any problems and record your actions the same way as you do usually with codegen.

Answer (score 11):

On updated versions of `playwright`, you can run:

```
npx playwright codegen --ignore-https-errors https://example.com
```

Additional options for `codegen` can be found running `npx playwright codegen --help`.